# Why doesn't forwarding work in this case?

Tags: r, ellipsis

I had some trouble to forward '...' in R.
I've found a solution but I still don't understand why my original code was incorrect. Maybe someone can explain it to me ?

I have prepared a reprex:

```
# modify a string with glue.
# z is an optional argument
fun_A <- function(my_string, ..., z = NULL){
  print(paste0("z value: ", as.character(z))) # do something with z here
  print(list(...)) # to test: print ... to check that all variables are still there

  my_string <- glue::glue(my_string, ...)
  my_string
}

# when fun_A() is used inside fun_B, 'z' must be filled with the same value in fun_A() and fun_B().
fun_B <- function(z, my_string, ...){
  my_string_mod <- rlang::enquo(my_string) %>%
    rlang::call_modify(z = z) %>%
    rlang::eval_tidy()
  my_string_mod
  # then other stuff, useless for the reprex
}

# calls fun_B() but for a specific string, now the argument of my_string are explicit.
fun_C_ok <- function(x, y){
  fun_B(z = "i am z",
        my_string = fun_A(my_string = "replace {x} and {y}.",
                          x = !!x, y = !!y)
  )
```

Everything works as I want:

In *fun_A()*, 'z' is missing as expected. 'x' and 'y' are changed as expected

```
> fun_A(my_string = "replace {x} and {y}.", x = "this", y = "that")
[1] "z value: "
$x
[1] "this"

$y
[1] "that"

replace this and that.
```

In *fun_B()*, 'z' is modified in fun_A() as expected. 'x' and 'y' are changed as expected

```
> fun_B(z = "i am z", my_string = fun_A(my_string = "replace {x} and {y}.", x = "this", y = "that"))
[1] "z value: i am z"
$x
[1] "this"

$y
[1] "that"

replace this and that.
```

In *fun_C_ok()*, 'z' is modified in fun_A() as expected. 'x' and 'y' are changed as expected

```
> fun_C_ok(x = "this", y = "that")
[1] "z value: i am z"
$x
[1] "this"

$y
[1] "that"

replace this and that.
```

At first, i wrote the last function like this (without the bang-bang operator (!!))

```
fun_C_notok <- function(x, y){
  fun_B(z = "i am z",
        my_string = fun_A(my_string = "replace {x} and {y}.",
                          x = x, y = y)
  )
}
```

It wasn't working, 'x' was not found by *glue* inside *fun_A()* but I don't understand why because 'x' and 'y' exist in list(...)

```
> fun_C_notok(x = "this", y = "that")

[1] "z value: i am z"
$x
[1] "this"

$y
[1] "that"

 Error in eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir) : 
  object 'x' not found 

11. eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir) 
10. eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir) 
9. .transformer(expr, env) 
8. (function (expr) 
{
    eval_func <- .transformer(expr, env)
    tryCatch(as.character(eval_func), error = function(e) { ... 
7. glue_data(.x = NULL, ..., .sep = .sep, .envir = .envir, .open = .open, 
    .close = .close, .na = .na, .transformer = .transformer, 
    .trim = .trim) 
6. glue::glue(my_string, ...) 
5. fun_A(my_string = "replace {x} and {y}.", x = x, y = y, z = "i am z") 
4. rlang::eval_tidy(.) 
3. rlang::enquo(my_string) %>% rlang::call_modify(z = z) %>% rlang::eval_tidy() 
2. fun_B(z = "i am z", my_string = fun_A(my_string = "replace {x} and {y}.", 
    x = x, y = y)) 
1. fun_C_notok(x = "this", y = "that")
```

Does somebody understand why *glue()* can't find 'x' in *fun_C_notok()* ??

Comment: I think it's pretty likely a bug in `glue::glue` or one of the functions it uses.  If you look at that traceback, you can see that it is doing very complicated stuff, and they probably made an assumption that doesn't hold in your example, e.g. that variables passed to it can be evaluated in the caller frame, not its parent as in your example.

Comment: Just tried your example using the `rgl:::subst` internal function instead of `glue::glue`, and it works fine.  `subst()` needs the string to be `"replace %x% and %y%."`, but can be used as a drop-in replacement in `funA`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have asked in the glue github if it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is a bug in `glue`, with a suggested fix here:  https://github.com/tidyverse/glue/issues/231#issuecomment-951129873 .  In the meantime, this appears to work:  specify the environment explicitly, by modifying your `funA` to this:

```
fun_A <- function(my_string, ..., z = NULL){
  print(paste0("z value: ", as.character(z))) # do something with z here
  print(list(...)) # to test: print ... to check that all variables are still there

  e <- list2env(list(...))
  my_string <- glue::glue(my_string, .envir = e, ...)
  my_string
}
```